# How to upgrade minor version of Postgresql on Mac OSX installed with Homebrew?

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I installed Postgres (version 9.6.2) on Mac OSX (High Sierra) using Homebrew last year. The latest 9.6 version is 9.6.8. How do I upgrade to 9.6.8? If I just do brew upgrade postgresql, it will skip to version 10. I only want to upgrade to the latest minor version of 9.6, which is 9.6.8. How should I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can upgrade from PostgreSQL 9.6.2 to the last 9.6.x (9.6.8 at the time of writing) by using:

```
brew upgrade postgresql@9.6
```

This works because there is a [versioned formula](https://docs.brew.sh/Versions) for the [PostgreSQL 9.6.x](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/postgresql@9.6.rb) line.

Comment: Thanks, but not working for me.

When I type `brew upgrade postgresql@9.6`, I get:

`Error: postgresql@9.6 not installed`, even though postgres appears to be installed at `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.2`, and when i run `psql --version` I get:

 `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.2`.

Any suggestions?  Btw, my brew version is `Homebrew 1.5.12`.

Comment: It might be because when I originally installed Postgres 9.6.2, I was using an earlier version of Homebrew, whereas versioned formula is a new-ish feature?   If so, how best to move forward?

Comment: Actually, the following question looks like exactly my issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391773/homebrew-upgrade-postgresql-to-latest-version-from-other-tap

Maybe someone will respond to that one!

Comment: Backup the database, then `brew remove postgresql` and `brew install postgresql@9.6`.